# SSIS Data Flow - sequential insert with required foreign key values

Tags: ssis, dataflow

Is it possible to insert to a initial table then using the inserted ID to be used in inserting to the main table that has a foreign key constraint between the columns in one data flow?

I am new to integration services and don't know the capabilities

Scenario:

TABLE A - ID
        - DESC

TABLE B - ID
        - A_ID
        - DESC

This is where A_ID is the foreign key (if its not obvious)

Can i create a single data flow with this kind of sequential flow of events or do I need to create another data flow for insertion of TABLE B after I inserted in table A.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no precedence constraints or containers in a data flow, so if you put both operations into one flow they execute in parallel and that means you can't make sure they will complete in the necessary order. So just use two data flows and then you can control the order in the control flow.

Comment: Thanks. What I did was to take out the FK constraints and place them after I inserted in both tables.

Comment: Coping and pasting the Data Flow in the Control Flow multiple times made things easy. Rename them. Link them together. Then went back inside them and deleted the parts that didn't pertain.

Answer (score 0):

You can have different "lanes" with different imports in one data flow task. These can be merged by using a merge task, where you can join by using your IDs. Generally, each "lane" contains one data stream which represents one table.

[image]

Image-source: http://sqlserverpedia.com/w/images/5/56/CWebb-Dataflow.png

If you have a look at the image, the tasks "Connections", "Commands" and "Sessions" will each have one data stream. As you can see, the merge task will handle two streams, so this way you can although pre-process data. (like having an initial table as you want it. But this will be parallel!)

If i am getting you right, you simply want to have a lookup. Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141821.aspx).

Comment: thanks for the reply. I get your explanation but it is not what i need. I have one data source but i need to insert to multiple tables. where data from the previous table will be used in the following tables. As what ive read, I need a script component to query from the database after I insert but im stuck at that point cause I dont know why "Dts" is not coming up as a global variable in my end..

Answer (score 0):

If I good understand you:

1. You need to insert data in `TABLE A`
2. When You insert data in `TABLE B` use [LOOKUP](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/SMcDonald/bidn-blog/621/ssis-lookup-task) element to Get Key from `TABLE A`.